# Got SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' in vendor.js in angular.js running inside container

Tags: angular, docker, offline-mode, rhel8

After building a docker image and extracted and loaded in an offline machine, application is rendering a blank page in RHEL 8.2. works fine in windows and in linux (I've tried with deepinOS)

Hi, I'm trying to dockerize one angular application. I have created image for that application. Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:18.13.0 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install -f
RUN npm install bootstrap -f
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Now, image has successfully built, and the container is running properly. Now my requirement is to run this angular container in an offline machine, so I've extracted the image in tar file and loaded in the offline machine. Offline machine am using is RHEL 8.2 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux). Image has addded, and container is running, but am getting the following error and in the portal, browser renders a blank page but title is coming properly in browser tab.

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' in vendor.js`

[image: Error screenshot]

For debugging information, application works fine when running directly without docker.

Please, help me to solve the issue.

Additionaly, css is not running in some pc's.(I would appreciate if this also got solved)

Thanks for the time.

Comment: How should we know about the problem if you don't share a single line of JS code?

Comment: There's no error in JS code(angular). It's running properly, only if I extract the image after dockerizing angular app and load it in offline machine, it is not working. Am getting the following error in browser console. SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' in vendor.js